# MySQL/PHP Concatenating condition operator (<= , >=) with string in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, operators, concatenation, where-clause

This is my first post,so i will do my best to be clear.
Here is my question :

suppose you have a var that contain an operator :
For example, `$var = "<=";`
And you are tempted to do this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE".$attr." ".$var." ".$value;
```

(where `$value` is an integer),
Am i allowed to do this ?
If yes,
i have tried the same thing in my PHP script but it doesn't work ! (except for `$var = "="`) although it did work in phpmyadmin.
(My code is little bit long, but if you want i can post it).
I really appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't think you can.  But even if you could, I would doubt that it was `best-practices` as the value is not type-checked and could result in problems.

Comment: Thank for the fast answer !
can you give any alternative ?

Comment: Use a switch statement to execute the appropriate query.

Comment: Ah okay Thanks man! (i am such an idiot XD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don`t have any space between WHERE and $attr, you will perhaps get your wanted effect by doing this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".$attr." ".$var." ".$value;
```

Or just

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE $attr  $var $value";
```

Try to echo $query to the browser, and copy&paste that into phpmyadmin.